# JS: How to make a for loop out of this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

1. I have to create a 20 column bar-chart. The bar on the very right gets updated every second with a random number which gives the bar its height. After one second the value gets transferred to its neighbour on the left and so on. To connect the values from the array to css, I created this piece of code. On the left (barchart) is connected to the div via querySelectorAll and then indexed with [i], on the right i take the corresponding value from the array. Since I need to do 20 bars, it would make sense to use a for loop, but I don't really know how to create it... Any ideas?

```
    const arr = [];
    let number = "";

    function timer() {
        setInterval(function () {
            number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            const barchart = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");

            barchart[4].style.height = number + "%";
            barchart[3].style.height = arr[4] + "%";
            barchart[2].style.height = arr[3] + "%";
            barchart[1].style.height = arr[2] + "%";
            barchart[0].style.height = arr[1] + "%";


            arr.push(number);

            if (arr.length > 5) {
                arr.shift();
            }
            console.log(arr);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

How to shorten this into a loop?

```
    barchart[4].style.height = number + "%";
    barchart[3].style.height = arr[4] + "%";
    barchart[2].style.height = arr[3] + "%";
    barchart[1].style.height = arr[2] + "%";
    barchart[0].style.height = arr[1] + "%";
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at what you have so far the first time the code runs `arr` is only initialized with no elements at all and you are attempting to reach out of bound indices which returns `undefined`

Moreover, you should not use initialize an array as a `const` if you are planning on changing the values it stores.

Now for the problem at hand:

Considering the bar on the far right is positioned at the last index of `barchart` and that `arr` contains the corresponding bar's heights:

```
//give the bar on the far right a random height.
barchart[barchart.length-1].style.height = number + "%";
//loop through barcharts array from end to start excluding the last bar.
for(let i=barchart.length-2; i>=0; i--)
  {
    //give each bar the height of his right neighbour
    barchart[i].style.height = arr[i+1] + "%";    
  }
```

Comment: Having `const arr = [];` is fine as `arr` is not being reassigned, just the elements it contains are being updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i = 0;i < 5;i++){
    barchart[i].style.height = arr[i+1] + "%";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just making sure `arr` has what you want before updating the bar chart, then you can just iterate over it.

Adding the new number and then making sure there are at most 5 numbers allows you to just iterate over all the elements in the array and it will only update the bars for the values it contains - no index out of bounds issues (you just get `undefined` with JS though.)

NOTE, I replaced `querySelectorAll` with `querySelector` as querySelectorAll returns a collection of matched elements rather than a single element.

```
const arr = [];
let number = "";

function timer() {
  setInterval(function() {
    number = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    
    arr.push(number);
    
    // make sure arr max's out at 5 numbers
    if (arr.length > 5)
      arr.shift();
  
    // update the bar chart(s)
    const barchart = document.querySelector(".bar");
  
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      barchart[i].style.height = arr[i] + "%";

    console.log(arr);
  }, 1000);
}
```